# jaeger collector running on aws ecs with grpc

Tags: go, grpc, jaeger

Installed jaeger collector image on AWS ECS with gRPC ALB.
The clients connect and send data successfully.

However, I see the following logs every 10 seconds

```
{
    "level": "info",
    "ts": 1647539810.5995932,
    "caller": "grpclog/component.go:71",
    "msg": "[transport]transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = \"transport is closing\"",
    "system": "grpc",
    "grpc_log": true
}
```

Has anyone seen this issue and know how to resolve it.

Comment: have you managed to resolve the issue ?

Comment: @PeterEskandar - nope - still the same noise